# How to make horizontal ordered list for multiple-choice questions?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a site for multiple-choice examination. The options must be in horizontal to save more space.

## Minimal Working Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Horizontal Lists</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        li.ans {
            color: red;
        }

        ol.option {
        }

            ol.option > li {
                list-style: lower-alpha;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            What is the capital of Japan?
            <ol class="option">
                <li>New York</li>
                <li>Jakarta</li>
                <li class="ans">Tokyo</li>
                <li>Kuala Lumpur</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            Who was granted a Noble prize for discovering photo electric effect?
            <ol class="option">
                <li>Mike Tyson</li>
                <li>Bill Gates</li>
                <li>Donald Trump</li>
                <li class="ans">Albert Einstein</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

## Output

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

## Question

How to make horizontal ordered list for multiple-choice questions?

Comment: There are **many, many** methods...what have you tried? Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ol.option {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 500px;
  }
```

Add above code to your inline style and be sure to learn more about **flexbox** for layout.